# SDWeb ImageでFirebaseから取得した画像をUIButtonにセットしたい

Tags: swift4, firebase

SDWebImageを用いてFirebaseから取得してきた画像をUIButtonのimageにセットしようとしているのですがうまくいきません。

```
 @IBOutlet weak var photoBtn: UIButton!
 @IBOutlet weak var removeBtn: UIButton!
 let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()

 func configure(isHidden: Bool, id: String, uid: String) {
        let reference = self.storageRef.child("photos/\(uid)/\(id).png")
        photoBtn.imageView?.sd_setImage(with: reference, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "noImg"))
    }
```

同じ処理をUIImageに対して行うとうまくいきます。

どこか間違っている点や、他の方法がありましたらご教示いただきたいです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIButton`の`imageView`プロパティの`image`を直接変更しようとしても動作しません。`setImage(_:for:)`メソッドを使用する必要があります。

SDWebImageはUIButtonのエクステンションも提供されているので、

```
photoBtn.sd_setImage(with: reference, forState: .normal, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "noImg"))
```

のように`UIButton`の`setImage(_:for:)`メソッドが使われるようにすると期待した通りに動くはずです。